How does $i(\ell_0 -\bar{\ell}_0)$ generates rotations?
In the book "String theory and M-theory" by Becker-Becker-Schwarz, the author says in chapter 2 page 61 that "conformal transformations in 2 dimensions consist of analytic coordinate transformations $z\to f(z)$ and $\bar{z}\to \bar{f}(\bar{z})$. To exhibit the generators, consider infinitesimal conformal transformations of the form $$z\to z'=z-\sum_n \varepsilon_n z^{n+1}\quad \text{and}\quad \bar{z}\to \bar{z}'=\bar{z}-\sum_n \bar{\varepsilon}_n \bar{z}^{n+1},\; n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
The corresponding infinitesimal generators are $$\ell_n =-z^{n+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\quad \text{and}\quad \bar{\ell}_n=-\bar{z}^{n+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}.$$
I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how  $i(\ell_0 -\bar{\ell}_0)$ generates rotations,  $(\ell_0 +\bar{\ell}_0)$ generates scalings, and $\ell_1$ and $\bar{\ell}_1$ generate special conformal transformation? I really want to learn them well. I would really grateful if someone could help about their calculations.

Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/830906/2451

@Qmechanic Could you please guide me about this question?

Hint: Try to go to polar coordinates $z=re^{i\theta}$.

This is merely an expansion of the hint from @Qmechanic from the comments. Write $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\overline{z}=re^{-i\theta}$. Using the chain rule yields:
\begin{align*}
\ell_0
=-z\partial_z
&=-re^{i\theta}\left(
\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\partial_r
+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial z}\partial_\theta
\right)
=-re^{i\theta}\left(
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\right)^{-1}\partial_r
+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial\theta}\right)^{-1}\partial_\theta
\right) \\
&=-re^{i\theta}\left(
e^{-i\theta}\partial_r
-\frac{i}{r}e^{-i\theta}\partial_\theta
\right)
=-r\partial_r
+i\partial_\theta.
\end{align*}
Analogously, you have (since the second summand takes down the exponent):
$$
\overline\ell_0
=\overline{z}\partial_{\overline{z}}
=-r\partial_r
-i\partial_\theta.
$$
This results in:
$$
i(\ell_0-\overline\ell_0)
=2\partial_\theta;
$$
$$
\ell_0+\overline\ell_0
=-2\partial_r.
$$

Thank you very much for your nice explanation. I got it now.
